Why is Flask not functioning on my raspberry pi?
I am attempting to run a flask program to stream from a camera on my raspberry pi. It wouldn't work so I tried it with another super simple script to return hello world and still returned as "this site can't be reached" on my browsers. I've tried multiple browsers and I've tried to add google to the firewall exemption. here is the code for the hello world script. I am up to date on raspian OS and I am using a raspberry pi 3 b+. The script runs and it tells me what ip to use but it seems inaccessible from any other device.
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

I have tried a different device, a different network, the same network, different browsers on each device, rebooting the pi, a different port. It seems to run off the pi, it says
* Debug mode: on
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx


Make sure port 5000 is open in the firewall.

the firewall in my router is set so port 5000 is open. Is there anywhere else I would need to do that for?

What is the actual value of xxx in this message: Running on http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5000? Is it 127.0.0.1?

yes it is, sorry, I am very new to network code and figured I should play it safe! that's just for the local network though correct?

@JohnCunnington Yes, it's only the local IP.

Flask, by default, won't serve your app to all addresses, but only to the address of the device it is running on (localhost or 127.0.0.1). Use:
app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0")

and it will serve to all addreses.
When you don't need it anymore, remove debug! With it, anyone who can access your app can also guess the token and run Python on your device!

Have you checked that Flask has opened the socket? If you have another SSH session open you could check with the command:
netstat -na | grep :<port>

If you find it, check iptables with following command:
iptables -L -v -n

Do this command as root or with sudo.

netstat returns tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN the iptables command is not found on my pi

also I am very noobish to anything to do with networking or webserver wise! I apologize if I write anything strangely.
